# Context bounds for type members or how to defer implicit resolution until member instantiation

Tags: scala, implicit, type-members

In the following example, is there a way to avoid that implicit resolution picks the `defaultInstance` and uses the `intInstance` instead?  More background after the code:

```
// the following part is an external fixed API

trait TypeCls[A] {
  def foo: String
}

object TypeCls {
  def foo[A](implicit x: TypeCls[A]) = x.foo

  implicit def defaultInstance[A]: TypeCls[A] = new TypeCls[A] {
    def foo = "default"
  }

  implicit val intInstance: TypeCls[Int] = new TypeCls[Int] {
    def foo = "integer"
  }
}

trait FooM {
  type A
  def foo: String = implicitly[TypeCls[A]].foo
}

// end of external fixed API

class FooP[A:TypeCls] { // with type params, we can use context bound
  def foo: String = implicitly[TypeCls[A]].foo
}

class MyFooP extends FooP[Int]

class MyFooM extends FooM { type A = Int }

object Main extends App {

  println(s"With type parameter: ${(new MyFooP).foo}")
  println(s"With type member:    ${(new MyFooM).foo}")
}
```

Actual output:

```
With type parameter: integer
With type member:    default
```

Desired output:

```
With type parameter: integer
With type member:    integer
```

I am working with a third-party library that uses the above scheme to provide "default" instances for the type class `TypeCls`.  I think the above code is a minimal example that demonstrates my problem.

Users are supposed to mix in the `FooM` trait and instantiate the abstract type member `A`.  The problem is that due to the `defaultInstance` the call of `(new MyFooM).foo` does not resolve the specialized `intInstance` and instead commits to `defaultInstance` which is not what I want.

I added an alternative version using type parameters, called `FooP` (P = Parameter, M = Member) which avoids to resolve the `defaultInstance` by using a context bound on the type parameter.

Is there an equivalent way to do this with type members?

EDIT: I have an error in my simplification, actually the `foo` is not a `def` but a `val`, so it is not possible to add an implicit parameter.  So no of the current answers are applicable.

```
trait FooM {
  type A
  val foo: String = implicitly[TypeCls[A]].foo
}

// end of external fixed API

class FooP[A:TypeCls] { // with type params, we can use context bound
  val foo: String = implicitly[TypeCls[A]].foo
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution in this specific case is have `foo` itself require an implicit instance of `TypeCls[A]`.
The only downside is that it will be passed on every call to `foo` as opposed to just when instantiating
`FooM`. So you'll have to make sure they are in scope on every call to `foo`. Though as long as the `TypeCls` instances are in the companion object, you won't have anything special to do.

```
trait FooM {
  type A
  def foo(implicit e: TypeCls[A]): String = e.foo
}
```

**UPDATE**: In my above answer I managed to miss the fact that `FooM` cannot be modified. In addition the latest edit to the question mentions that `FooM.foo` is actually a `val` and not a `def`.

Well the bad news is that the API you're using is simply broken. There is no way `FooM.foo` wille ever return anything useful (it will always resolve `TypeCls[A]` to `TypeCls.defaultInstance` regardless of the actual value of `A`). The only way out is to override `foo` in a derived class where the actual value of `A` is known, in order to be able to use the proper instance of `TypeCls`. Fortunately, this idea can be combined with your original workaround of using a class with a context bound (`FooP` in your case):

```
class FooMEx[T:TypeCls] extends FooM {
  type A = T
  override val foo: String = implicitly[TypeCls[A]].foo
}
```

Now instead of having your classes extend `FooM` directly, have them extend `FooMEx`:

```
class MyFoo extends FooMEx[Int]
```

The only difference between `FooMEx` and your original `FooP` class is that `FooMEx` **does** extend `FooM`, so `MyFoo` is a proper instance of `FooM` and can thus be used with the fixed API.

Comment: sorry I noticed that the external API uses a `val` instead of `def`, so this is not possible...

Comment: Oh my bad, somehow I managed to miss the fact that you can't modify `FooM`. There's another solution then, see my update.

Comment: Okay thanks, I kind of feared that is simply broken.  Btw. the API I am talking about is ScalaCheck, having a default `Shrink` instances that does nothing.

Comment: ScalaCheck? That's a bit surprising. So if `TypeCls` is actually `Shrink`, what is `FooM `?

Comment: TypeCls is `Shrink`, `FooM` is `Commands`, `type A` is `type State` and what I wanted to do is shrinking `State` inside of `private implicit val shrinkActions` (https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/commands/Commands.scala#L239)

Comment: Indeed, it does seem like there is no way to define the `Shrink[State]` instance and have it taken into account in `shrinkActions`. You should file a bug (as overriding in this case is not very practical, the methods that use `Shrink[Action]` - the ones calling `forAll` on actions - are *huge*, and you clearly don't want to copy paste all that in your derived class).

Answer (score 1):

Can you copy the code from the third party library. Overriding the method does the trick.

```
class MyFooM extends FooM { type A = Int 
  override def foo: String = implicitly[TypeCls[A]].foo}
```

It is a hack, but I doubt there is anything better.

I do not know why this works the way it does. It must be some order in which the type alias are substituted in the implicitly expression.

Only an expert in the language specification can tell you the exact reason.

Comment: I had to edit my question because the `foo` is a `val` and not a `def`, so no implicit parameter list for me...

Comment: He does not use any implicit parameter list. The proposed solution above would still work with a val, you just have to change `override def` with `override val`

Comment: absolutely right, I mixed this up, this works as expected but the point that was not known is that in the actual API, the `val` is `private` too, so no overriding.

Comment: Just drop the override keyword. 

val foo: String = implicitly[TypeCls[A]].foo}

This works too.